# ggplot confidence bands from gam predict$fit and predict$se.fit

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam, mgcv

I have the following variables:

`prod`: positive integer

`tenure`: positive numeric

`cohort`: factor

Here is some simulated data with these specifications.

```
set.seed(123)
my_data <- data.frame(prod   = rnbinom(10000, mu = 2.5, size = 1.5),
                      tenure = rexp(10000),
                      cohort = factor(sample(2011:2014, size = 10000, replace = TRUE,
                                             prob = c(0.17, 0.49, 0.26, 0.08))))
```

I have fit the following model using `mgcv:gam`:

```
library(mgcv)
mod <- gam(prod ~ s(tenure, by = cohort) + cohort, data = my_data, family = nb())
```

The get the predictions and their standard errors:

```
preds   <- predict(mod, se.fit = TRUE)
my_data <- data.frame(my_data,
                      mu   = exp(preds$fit),
                      low  = exp(preds$fit - 1.96 * preds$se.fit),
                      high = exp(preds$fit + 1.96 * preds$se.fit))
```

It is fairly straightforward to use `package:ggplot2` to acquire the smoothed predictions `mu` for each cohort (while also forcing the smoother to have positive values):

```
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
library(splines)
my_plot <-
  ggplot(my_data, aes(x = tenure, y = mu, color = cohort)) %>%
  + geom_smooth(method  = "glm",
                formula = y ~ ns(x, 3),
                family  = "quasipoisson",
                fill    = NA)
```

But I would like to have smoothed confidence bands from the GAM. How do I add those?

**Not the answer**

1. Remove `fill = NA`. Nope. Those confidence bands would be infinitely small because the prediction by tenure is exactly the same within a cohort.
2. Add a call to `geom_ribbon(aes(x = tenure, ymin = low, ymax = high))`. Nope. That gives me a super-wiggly, non-smoothed confidence band.
3. Use `package:ggvis`! No `package:ggvis` answers, please, unless there is no way to do this in `ggplot2`. My current plotting framework is `ggplot2`, and I'm sticking with it for now unless I must switch in order to do this plot.

Comment: (If you want working code you should provide data.)

Comment: `geom_smooth` should work, as demonstrated in [the ggplot2 example](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_smooth.html). A side note, why use `%>%` in your ggplot2 call? I would expect a plus there.

Comment: Thanks. I do include a `+` operator, as you can see. I use `%>%` so I can pipe plot elements together on different lines. I think this is what `ggvis` does (yes I'll switch to `ggvis` someday).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, format that as an answer and I will check the ever-loving StackOverflow out of it.

Comment: @BondedDust, there's your data, but it looks like it wasn't necessary in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(mgcv)

set.seed(123)
my_data <- data.frame(prod   = rnbinom(10000, mu = 2.5, size = 1.5),
                      tenure = rexp(10000),
                      cohort = factor(sample(2011:2014, size = 10000, replace = TRUE,
                                             prob = c(0.17, 0.49, 0.26, 0.08))))
mod <- gam(prod ~ s(tenure, by = cohort) + cohort, data = my_data, family = nb())
preds   <- predict(mod, se.fit = TRUE)
my_data <- data.frame(my_data,
                      mu   = exp(preds$fit),
                      low  = exp(preds$fit - 1.96 * preds$se.fit),
                      high = exp(preds$fit + 1.96 * preds$se.fit))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x = tenure, y = prod, color = cohort)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(aes(ymin = low, ymax = high, y = mu), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: I think this does not work. I get "Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymin, ymax". Those bands might be new values calculated by ggplot2.

Comment: Maybe difference in versions? Me, ggplot2_2.2.1 & mgcv_1.8-24. It's true that values you calculated are being used in spite of the warning. Do we delete these conversation?

Comment: I'm using ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 and mgcv_1.8-23. Sure, I'll delete this comment in a few hours.